# ¿Cual es el equivalente de la palabra clave "TO" de VBA en C#?

Tags: c#

Estoy pasando codigo de vba a c# pero no encuentro la palabra clave "**To**" para c#
Ejemplo:

Xl = -1208721221
Xr = -38092073

```vb
Const ROUND = 16
private m_pBox(0 To ROUND + 1) As Long

Private static Sub DecryptBlock(Xl As Long, Xr As Long)
  Dim temp As Long
  temp = Xr
  Xr = Xl Xor m_pBox(ROUNDS + 1)
  Xl = temp Xor m_pBox(ROUNDS)
End Sub
```

¿y también me podrían explicar qué hace esta línea de código en VBA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las sentencias siguientes...

```vb
Const ROUND = 16
private m_pBox(0 To ROUND + 1) As Long
```

... equivalen a...

```vb
private m_pBox(0 To 17) As Long
```

... lo que resulta en crear un arreglo con 18 elementos (0 a 17).

En C# no existe una sintaxis equivalente con el `To` para los arreglos ya que es implícito que todos los arreglos comienzan con el índice 0, y solo necesitas indicar la talla del arreglo.

De modo que en C#, el equivalente sería simplemente:

```
private const int ROUND = 16;
private long[] m_pBox = long[16 + 2];
```

... o:

```
private long[] m_pBox = long[18];
```

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme, mira acabo de editar el codigo de ejemplo para tener un mejor contexto de lo que trato de pasar a c#

Comment: Hola Maot. No estoy seguro que entiendo la razón de tu edición ya que no tiene impacto en la respuesta a tu pregunta en cuanto al `To`. A menos que sutilmente estás tratando de que te traduzcamos el resto del método, lo que ya sería una pregunta distinta...

Comment: Tienes razon , gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 1):

sin mal no recuerdo, esta sintaxis te sirve para declarar un array por rango de valores. En tu caso concreto para pasarlo a c# no tienes problema porque los arrays ya empiezan en 0 y la solución que te ha propuesto @pikoh es correcta: `private long[] m_pBox = new long[ROUND + 2];`